# Django possible circular import

Tags: python, django, exception, django-models, django-views

I'm setting up a new "Game" website. I have started a new app Games, set up the games/models.py with the code (below). After makemigrations game and migrate, I was able to log into Admin and add entries.

Then I set to create the URLs, views, one template. After creating them, when I runserver, I get the following error:

> url_patterns
> raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included
> URLconf '<module 'games.urls' from
> '/home/mackley/PycharmProjects/alphabet/games/urls.py'>' does not
> appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the
> file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

The first thing I noticed is that the top line (*from django.conf import settings*) of games/models.py (using PyCharm) is greyed out. I don't know if that has anything to do with the error:

Can anyone spot where I have made a mistake? Here is the relevant code.

```
# games/models.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    answer_one = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    answer_two = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    answer_three = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    answer_four = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    answer_five = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    answer_six = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    answer_seven = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    payout_total = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=1.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('game_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

games/admin

```
   # games/admin.py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Game
    
    admin.site.register(Game)
```

config/urls

```
# config/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('games/', include('games.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

games/url

```
# games/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import GameListView

urlpattrns = [
    path('', GameListView.as_view(), name='game_list'),
]
```

games/views.py

```
# games/views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Game

class GameListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'game_list.html'
```

Comment: Not sure if it's just a copy/paste error but urlpatterns is misspelled in games/urls.py. That can cause this error.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, this happens when django can't find valid urlpatterns in your urlconf. There could be many reasons for this but the one that seems most likely to me in your case is that urlpatterns is misspelled as 'urlpattrns' in games/urls.py. Try fixing the typo then running again.

Comment: Oh, my goodness,Taimur Ibrahim. Thank you for seeing that. Working too tired, I suppose.